# fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php

I get this **warning** spammed couple thousand times, making my browser lag:

**fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\XMPPHP\XMLStream.php on line 403**

```
protected $socket;

                fclose($this->socket);
                $this->socket = NULL;
                return false;
```

I am quite new to PHP and already googled this. However, I am not able to fix it. I tried to check if $socket is valid before calling fclose() but that didn't help either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I tried to check if $socket is valid* Please show us more context around your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you are calling the above code twice, or calling it even if the socket was not first successfully opened.

Try having a "if (is_resource($this->socket)) { .. }" around the code.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my Problem!